# What is the importance of trailing padding bytes in that case?

Tags: c, alignment, structure, padding

I have a structure of the following type:

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned char      A;
   unsigned long int  B;
   unsigned short int C;
}
```

According to the alignment requirements of each basic data type and the alignment requirement of the whole structure, the allocation in memory will be like that:

[image]

My question is what is the importance of those trailing padding bytes as long as each structure member is naturally aligned to its size and could be accessed by our processor in one cycle (assuming that the bus size of processor is 32-bit) without alignment faults.

Also, if we declared an array of "2" of this structure, without taking into consideration the trailing bytes, the allocation in memory will be as following:

[image]

Each member in the two structures is naturally aligned to its size and could be accessed in one cycle without alignment faults.
So, what is the importance of trailing bytes in this case ?!

Comment: The layout of the second element in your array is different from the first (number of padding bytes after the Ax). The alignment requirement of a struct to be as big as the biggest alignment requirement of any member is indeed to guarantee the alignment of the members in an array of such structs.

Comment: It still needs to be aligned when you create an array of these structures, thus the padding at the end.  Your hack takes care of alignment but makes it impossible to pass &array[1] to a function that takes a struct*, it has no way to know that the padding is different.  Simply indexing the array and accessing the struct members in itself would be costly as well, pretty rough on the prefetcher.

Comment: BTW, nice pictures - what did you draw these in?

Comment: @Andres Microsoft Word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments from Bryan Olivier and Hans Passant are both right.

Essentially, you have answered your own question: In the 2nd drawing, the alignment of the members of both the first and second array item are correct. If the compiler could layout structures like this there would be no importance to the trailing pad bytes. But it can't.

In C, a structure's layout and size must be the same for every instance of a structure. In your second example, the sizeof(array[0]) is 10 and sizeof(array[1]) is 8. The address of B2 is only two greater than A2, but &B1 is four greater than &A1.

It's more than just alignment - it's ensuring a constant layout and size while still ensuring alignment. Even then it would not require trailing pad bytes if the first byte was aligned, but as you have noticed if you add arrays, then you need them.

**Alignment+Layout/Size+Arrays => trailing pad is required**.

Comment: I should note that this is all discussing how actual C compilers need to do things on real machines for efficiency, not some hypothetical C implementation. The location and padding of structures is an implementation detail and should relied upon.

Answer (score 2):

As Andres said, the compiler can't generate special layout to every member in the array of structures.

For example, assume that the programmer has defined a structure with the following type

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned char      A;
   unsigned long int  B;
   unsigned short int C;
} myStructureType;
```

And then the programmer has created an instance of this type:

```
myStructureType myStructure;
```

The compiler will allocate memory to `myStructure` as following:
[image]

If the programmer has decided to create an array of `myStructureType`, the compiler will repeat the previous pattern in memory by the number of array's elements as following:

[image: Assume that an array of "2" is declared]

If the compiler neglects the trailing padding bytes, the memory will become misaligned as following

[image]

32-bit modern processor will need two memory cycles and some masking operations to fetch B1 (the element B in the index "1" of the array of structures). However, an old processor will fire an alignment faults.

That's why the trailing padding was important in this case